# Telerik RadDatePicker issue with Daylight Saving Time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, client, raddatepicker

When I select the first day of Daylight Saving Time period, the RadDatePicker delays the selected day in 1 hour, making it display the previous day.

And the control appears to do that before ANY client-side event.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Here's an example: [Telerik example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/clientapi/defaultcs.aspx). It's just select the day at the init of Daylight Saving Time.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to say which particular time zone you are in, as well as which date you are referring to? Experimented with a few time zones and their daylight saving time dates but could not reproduce this.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/error-on-date-components http://www.telerik.com/forums/date-picker-selection-issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the "Daylight Saving" in the client machine.
It worked in my tests and in my customers.

Thanks,

Marcelo